# Why am I getting the last row with zeros in it. I'm not able to remove them. If I do a lastRow-1, I get an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

```
 function addRowTotal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet4");
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,3).getValues();

  var totalsArray=[];
  data.forEach(function(row){
    var name= row[0];
    var price= row[1];
    var qty = row[2];
    var tot=price*qty;
    var doz=price*12;
    row.push(tot,doz);
    //Logger.log (data);
    totalsArray.push([tot,doz]); 
    Logger.log(totalsArray);
  })
  sheet.getRange(2,4,lastRow,2).setValues(totalsArray);
}
```

**Question:** Why am I getting the last row with zeros in it. I'm not able to remove them. If I do a lastRow-1, I get an error.

Comment: In your script, at `var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,3).getValues();`, the next of next of the last row is retrieved, because the value is retrieved from 2nd row. If you don't want to include the row which has `0` at the columns "D" and "E", how about modifying to `var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow - 2,3).getValues()` and also, from `sheet.getRange(2,4,lastRow,2).setValues(totalsArray)` to `sheet.getRange(2,4,lastRow - 2,2).setValues(totalsArray)`? But I cannot understand about your goal. So I post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

`var data` gets an extra blank row. The [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) function with 4 arguments is defined like that: `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`. In this example, `sheet.getLastRow()` is **5** and you want to start from row **2**, therefore
`getRange(2, 1, 5, 3)`. This will return a range which starts from row **2** and  considers **5** rows: `2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th`. But the 6th row is **blank**. In order to factor this in you should deduct one row from `getLastRow()` like that: `lastRow=sheet.getLastRow()-1`.

---

### Solution:

```
 function addRowTotal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet4");
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,3).getValues();

  var totalsArray=[];
  data.forEach(function(row){
    var name= row[0];
    var price= row[1];
    var qty = row[2];
    var tot=price*qty;
    var doz=price*12;
    row.push(tot,doz);
    totalsArray.push([tot,doz]); 
  })
  
  sheet.getRange(2,4,lastRow,2).setValues(totalsArray);
}
```

---

### Output:

[image: example]